# Excel search upwards

Tags: microsoft-excel

Consider this example excel table:

```
    A         B                                                          C
|  Time  |  Action                                              |  
|     1  |  Adam arrives                                        |  
|     2  |  Adam leaves                                         |  
|     3  |  Berta arrives                                       |  
|     4  |  Berta says: Huhu!                                   |  
|     5  |  Berta leaves                                        |  ?
|     6  |  Caesar arrives                                      |  
|     7  |  Doris arrives                                       |  
|     8  |  Caesar says: Have you recently seen Brutus, Doris?  |  
|     9  |  Adam arrives                                        |  
|    10  |  Doris says: No! I think he wants to kill you!       |  
|    11  |  Adam leaves                                         |  ??
|    12  |  Caesar says: I know                                 |  
|    13  |  Doris leaves                                        |  ???
|    14  |  Caesar leaves                                       |  ????
```

I want to calculate how long the people were in the chat and display it in column C. Lets exclude all the stuff like *if Bx contains leaving message, empty if not* and *parse name from leaving message* and concentrate only on the duration calculation. For that, in the cells marked with `?`, `??`, `???` and `????`, I need a formula like **search for "$person arrives" in the range B2 to B$currentLine-1 and give me the line of the last result**. With that information, I can then get the time.

Is that even possible?

Comment: I'll answer your last question, yes it is possible. But you'll need to provide a lot more information, and give us examples of what you tried. If you want some hints, then I'm thinking you'll need a combination of if(), ifs(), index(), match(), find(), left(), and/or concat()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in C2 and give it an appropriate cell number format then drag it down the column.

```
=IF(RIGHT(B2, 7)=" leaves", A2-AGGREGATE(14, 7, (A$2:A2)/(B$2:B2=SUBSTITUTE(B2, " leaves", " arrives")), 1), "")
```

Comment: Still it gives "2" as answer for 2nd time when Adam leaves, instead of correct "9"

Comment: Adam's second arrival is at 9; second departure at 11. In what way is 11 minus 9 not 2?

Comment: I think both of you do basically the same thing, one with `MAX(...)`, one with `AGGREGATE(14,...)`, and you both use a trick for the ranges with the condition which was completely new to me up to now. Thank you!!

Comment: Hi Jeeped, sorry this is off-topic, but why'd you nuke your SO account?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 - Six hours after I hit 100K in rep, I was suspended for 30 days by the mods and they removed ~650 rep points (Yvette Colomb in particular seemed to have it out for me for some imaginary reason). I'm still pretty damned pissed off about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula to solve your problem:

`=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("leaves",B2),0)>0,MAX($A1:$A$2*($B1:$B$2=SUBSTITUTE(B2,"leaves","arrives"))),"")`

This is an array formula, so need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> after pressing it

[image]

Comment: I think both of you do basically the same thing, one with `MAX(...)`, one with `AGGREGATE(14,...)`, and you both use a trick for the ranges with the condition which was completely new to me up to now. Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

*Reverse lookup formula can be used to fix the issue:*

[image]

- Formula in Cell `F95`, fill it down.

  ```
  =IF(LEFT(D94,5)<>LEFT(D95,5),IFERROR(INDEX(C95:C108,MATCH(LEFT(D95,(FIND(" ",D95,1)-1))&" Arrives",D95:D108,0),1),""),"")
  ```
- Key feature of this Formula is:

`MATCH(LEFT(D95,(FIND(" ",D95,1)-1))&" Arrives"`

- Finds, `Time` in `Column C` for the Names with string `Arrives`.

*You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: I fail to see how this solves the problem. I do not simply want to repeat the time of arrival *in the same line*, I want to determine the time of arrival *when the person leaves*.

Comment: @Bowi,,, it's doing the same,, that's the reason all formula searches same sequence `1, 3, 6, 7, 9`,, determine the time of arrival when the person leaves,, just getting in reverse like `Adam` leaves at `2` & his arrival is `1` & `Breata` leaves at `5` but her arrival before that is, `3`.

Comment: It is at the wrong place. I need the time of arrival in the line of the person leaving.

Comment: @Bowi,, it's key to execute `IFERROR(INDEX(,,` part,, if `True` & blank space if `False` !!

Comment: I took your formula as you wrote it (just translated it to German) and I got exactly the result you got in your screenshot. *But that does not solve the problem*. I do not want to know the arrival time *at the time of arrival*, I want to know the last arrival time *at the time of leaving*. And I still do not get what you mean with checking for `LEFT(D94,5)<>LEFT(D95,5)` – are you assuming that no name is longer than 5 characters?

Comment: @Bowi,, sometimes trick need to apply,, and is/are purely based on situation,, for the current data set (name) test  5 characters are enough to execute further,, if in case data set has longer name then trick test may be altered,, I don't  think cell position for result makes any crucial effect ,, when formula returns correct sequence,, finding Arrival before leaving .

Comment: Okay, then I understand the check. But: I do not need a sequence of arrivals. Like said in the question, *I want to calculate how long the people were in the chat and display it in column C*. I cannot see how the sequence of arrival times can help me with that. Maybe you could add that step to your answer?

Comment: Or maybe I still misunderstand you?